# How to get both the text + images copied in clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard

I am using MS-WORD for copying content to a rich editor. 
I need to use both the text + images which were copied from a MS-WORD file (via CTRL+A) into the editor (via CTRL+V).

In order to achieve that I am using this code:

```
    function handlePaste (e) {
        var clipboardData, pastedData;

        // Stop data actually being pasted into div
        e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

        // Get pasted data via clipboard API
    clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;

    pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');

    // Do whatever with pasteddata
    alert(pastedData);
}

document.getElementById('editableDiv').addEventListener('paste', handlePaste);
```

The issue with this code is that I am getting only the text from clipboard.
Here is the screenshot:

[image]

as you can see I am getting just text copied from word file and not the images.

Is there any solution on capturing images too along with text present in clipboard.

Right now I am using Chrome to check that functionality.

Here is the JSFiddle for the same:

https://jsfiddle.net/swL8ftLs/247/

Comment: Hey I know this is an old issue but do you mind posting the `clipboardData` serialized i.e. with JSON.stringify?

Answer (score 2):

When users copy/paste text + images, there is no file entity in clipboardData. File entity only actives on single file copy/paste.

To resolve this issue, we need:

- Read `text/html` data, and:

  - Find img elements in `text/html` and store them(for example, named as `htmlImages`)
- Read `text/rtf` data which includes image hex source, then:

  - Find image entities by match `\\pngblip` and `\\jpegblip` and convert them to a list of dataUrl(for example, named as `dataUrls`):

    - Get image type
    - Get hex source string
    - Convert hex to base64 string
    - Combine image type and base64 string to a dataurl string

      - You can also implement other handler to convert the base64 string to blob or upload the image content to cloud
- Replace the `src` attribute of elements in `htmlImages`, by values in `dataUrls`

  - Only replace the `src` starting with 'file:///'

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it helped me a lot!!! I used peg.js to build a picture in rtf content parser, with a grammar based on the rtf specifications. It was a pain in the a.. to implement but it's working!!!